# Xamarin.Forms: Soft Keyboard on iOS hides views

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am using a plug in in order to move the whole view up to get make the entries visible when the keyboard would hide them:

```
Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.Enable = true;
```

Many posts refer to this plug in and it does the job of pushing the view up very fine: however: once I close the keyboard again, the view isnt restored perfectly but instead a little bit is cut off at the bottom. Since I sometimes have buttons down there that are now cut off it is not a solution for me.

I tried multiple plug ins, they all do the same.

Does anyone here have a good solution to it?

On android everything works fin eautomatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by wrapping all entrys that were affected by a scrollview.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution ! You could accept the answer , which will help more people who has the similar issue :)